# Maven: build another war-project when current project has been built

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I have two war projects - A and B. B project includes A project at building time and is deployed to server. A project is not deployed to server.

B includes A this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
     <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

What I want - every time I build project A, project B must be build when building of project A is over. How can I do that?

Comment: How does B include A? Is it a child project?

Comment: @Lutz Horn I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Convert the two projects into Maven modules (i.e. copy them as folders into a Maven project) and then add this to your POM:

   ```
   <modules>
       <module>A</module>
       <module>B</module>
   </modules>
   ```

   Longer explanation: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html
2. Use a [CI server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) with two jobs (one for A and one for B) and use the tools of the CI server to define the dependency.